# Exporting vector tiles from Mapbox Studio?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

Using MapBox Studio, I created a new tileset, uploaded a zipped shapefile and styled it. Now, I want to export vector tiles so I can self-host them. While searching, I found many indications that exporting vector tiles was *possible* but nothing explaining where or how to do it.

How do I export my data as vector tiles?

Comment: Can post a link where you found that it is possible to export vector files in MapBox Studio?

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio-classic/issues/1453

Answer (score 2):

You can always export MBTiles (vector tiles) using Mapbox Studio, but only using the oldest version (Mapbox Studio Classic). It have options to import many formats and can export MBTiles. Notice that it is a standalone application [MapBox Studio Classic](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-mapbox-studio-classic/).